What does this headset symbol on my phone means?
What does this headset symbol on the notification mean, and how can I remove it?


Welcome George! I noticed your question is tagged with multiple versions of Android.  Which is applicable version of Android?

Also which device is it?

@beeshyams as far as I know the more important question is not left/right but on the side of the WiFi/mobile network strength icons or the other as I have seen screenshots when a right-to-left language is used the icons can also be reversed...
